# Subscribing to podcasts with an iPod without iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod, podcasts, subscription

I wish to have a software that:

1. Downloads new podcast episodes to my computer.
2. Syncs the files with my iPod whenever I connect it

I don't want the software to be iTunes.

After searching, I see the "songbird"'s iPod extension is not in development anymore.  I also see the "Juice" is not being developed anymore (although a bunch of people say they might take on the project).

Can anyone propose to me a good solution.  I would prefer a free open source solution (if it is possible)

Comment: iTunes has the feature build-in, which is why development slowed on these add-ons.

What does/doesn't iTunes do that you don't like?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Honestly - it's not OSS.  When I can, I'd rather use that.

Comment: You're going to be hard pressed to find something.  Apple, by its nature, is very proprietary.  Heck, even Winamp doesn't support iPods.  You can try some of the tools here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_podcatchers , but if you really want OSS, you're going to have to ditch that iPod and go with something else.

Comment: On second thought, Songbird is the go-to OSS replacement for iTunes, so that might be your best bet for something that's kept up-to-date.

http://www.getsongbird.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songbird_%28software%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so then you need to have an iPhone, iPad or at least an iPod touch.

I don't know of any other podcast downloading app that works with an iPod. Why don't you use iTunes? I love it.

Visit my tech blog at http://right-now-in-tech.blogspot.com/